# How to estimate the median survival with upper and lower confidence limits for the median at 90% confidence levels?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival, survminer

My goal is estimate the median survival with upper and lower confidence limits for the median at 90% confidence levels, using a survfit object.

```
churn_dat <-read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/square/pysurvival/master/pysurvival/datasets/churn.csv")
churn_dat <- churn_dat %>% filter(months_active > 0)
```

```
#create a function of  the dataframe by sizes
boot <- function(size,n_sims){
#1. filter data into a particular size
df <- churn_dat %>% filter(company_size == size)
n = nrow(df)
#2. run the bootstrap
experiments = tibble(experiment = rep(1:n_sims, each = n),
                     index = sample(1:n, size = n * n_sims, replace = TRUE),
                     time_star = df$months_active[index],
                     event_star = df$churned[index])
return(experiments)
}
```

```
#create a function for plotting
plot_boot_data <- function(experiments){
  fit <- survfit(Surv(time_star, event_star) ~ experiment, data = experiments)
  #get the median of surv
  med <- surv_median(fit)
  med <- data.frame(med = med$median)
  ggplot(med , aes(x = med, fill= med)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = .8)+theme_bw()
}
```

```
df_10to50 <- boot("10-50",10)
plot_boot_data(df_10to50)
```

#### I have found the similar function i.e. surv_median() to do it, but the confidence levels is at 95 %

How can i construct the same thing with confidence levels set to 90 %

Comment: The `surv_median` function assumes that the column in the table element of the survfit object will be labeled exactly as "0.95CL" so if you call survfit with `conf.int=0.9` it will give you an error:  "Column `0.95LCL` doesn't exist." Appears that Terry Therneau has provided the ability to set the confidence level at whatever you want, but the deficiency lies with the author of `surv_median`. So this would seem to be request to send to the maintainer of pkg:survminer. I suppose you could hack the `surv_median` function so that it wasn't so simple-minded.

Answer (score 1):

The `surv_median`-function in pkg:`survminer` is essentially doing what someone doing a screen scrape of the console would do after running the non-exposed `survmean` function in pkg:`survival`. (Note the need for the triple-colon (':::') extraction operator from package survival.) `surv_median` uses the hard coded column names and so is unable to deal with a `fit`-object that was constructed with a different value of the `conf.int` parameter in the results of a call to `survfit`. If you want the output of the `survmean`-function from such a call, it's not at all difficult. Using your data:

```
fit <- survfit(Surv(time_star, event_star) ~ experiment, data = df_10to50, conf.int=0.9)
med <- survival:::survmean(fit,rmean=FALSE)
med  # result is a named list
#------------
$matrix
              records n.max n.start events    rmean se(rmean) median 0.9LCL 0.9UCL
experiment=1      673   673     673    298 7.347565 0.2000873      7      5     12
experiment=2      673   673     673    309 7.152863 0.2028425      6      5     10
experiment=3      673   673     673    298 7.345891 0.2068490      9      5     12
experiment=4      673   673     673    323 7.035011 0.1981676      5      4      7
experiment=5      673   673     673    313 7.044400 0.2074104      6      5      9
experiment=6      673   673     673    317 7.061878 0.2021348      6      4      9
experiment=7      673   673     673    311 7.029602 0.2081835      5      4      9
experiment=8      673   673     673    301 7.345766 0.2032876      9      6     10
experiment=9      673   673     673    318 6.912700 0.2050143      7      5      9
experiment=10     673   673     673    327 6.988065 0.1990601      5      4      7

$end.time
 [1] 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12
```

If you wanted the median and bounds at 0.9 confidence level it could be obtained with:

```
med$matrix[ 1 , 7:9]  # using numbers instead of column names.
#----------
median 0.9LCL 0.9UCL 
     7      5     12
```

I'm afraid there is not a sufficient description of your goal of the  process of getting there for me to make sense of the dplyr/magrittr chain of logic, so I'm unable to fill in the proper places in the boot function or the handling of its output by `ggplot2`. I was initially very confused because you were using a function named `boot` and I thought you were doing bootstrapped analysis, but there didn't seem to be any mechanism for getting any bootstrapped results, i.e. no randomized selection of rows in an indexable dataset.

If you still wanted to make a purpose-built variant of surv_median you might try modifying this line inside the code:

```
.table <- .table %>% dplyr::select_(
                       .dots = c("strata", "median", "`0.95LCL`", "`0.95UCL`"))
```

I wasn't able to figure out what `surv_median` was doing with the "strata" column since it didn't match the output of `survmean`, but that probably because it was using `summary.survfit` rather than going directly to the function that `summary.survfit` calls to do the calculations. So happy hacking.